# leap year or a leap year

Tags: zero-article

> The  year  with  an  extra day  is  called  **leap  year.**

This sentence is from an article about "Calendar".

I want to know why the article is dropped before **leap year**. In my opinion, the article should use as "leap year" is the name of a year "a year, which happens every four".
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess it's not wrong to omit the article but i would still say that "a leap year" is correct.

Comment: An article is definitely required.

Comment: Yes, it should have the article.